# timestamp SQL to Excel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel

If this is a duplicate, please let me know, I haven't found anything.

I have written a php file that can read content from a database table and write it into a excel `.xls` file.
Everything works fine except by that timestamps. In my generated `.xls` file every timestamp is being replaced by #######, as well as some telephone numbers. Above is a screenshot[image]

I might guess it has something to do with colons `:` or hyphens `-`, but I can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*******EDIT LINES 3-8*******/
$DB_Server = "localhost"; //MySQL Server    
$DB_Username = "xxxxxx"; //MySQL Username     
$DB_Password = "xxxxxx";             //MySQL Password     
$DB_DBName = "xxxxxx";         //MySQL Database Name  
$DB_TBLName = "xxxxxx"; //MySQL Table Name   
$filename = "downloaded_table";         //File Name
//create MySQL connection   

$sql = "Select * from $DB_TBLName"; //Modify query here

/*******YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE*******/    
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
//select database   
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());   
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());    
$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/   
//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
}
print("\n");    
//end of printing column names  
//start while loop to get data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";
        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
        {
            if(!isset($row[$j]))
                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
            elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
            else
                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
        }
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
        $schema_insert .= "\t";
        print(trim($schema_insert));
        print "\n";
    }   
?>
```

Please help

Comment: Please stop using the old, deprecated MySQL interface, and start using MySQLi or PDO

Comment: This script was made a while ago, in all my modern projects I use MySQLi @MarkBaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `######` is shown in MS Excel when the data in a cell is too long for the column width.... the data inside the cell is still correct, as you can see if you select one of those cells and look at the value displayed in the cell content bar

As you're only creating a CSV file, you can't control the width of the cells, so you'll have to live with it.... unless you want to create a real Excel file, when you can set column widths explicitly

Comment: Thank you! I feel like an idiot now I haven't noticed that myself lol. Any documentation you would recommend me for learning how to create a real Excel file?

Comment: I have a vested interest in [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) as the lead developer and coordinator